# How can I add a VM into a Load Balancer within Azure using Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform

I have been looking through the Terraform.io docs and its not really clear.

I know how to add a VM to a LB through the Azure portal, just trying to figure out how to do with with Terraform.

I do not see an option in the azurerm_availability_set or azurerm_lb  to add a VM.

Please let me know if anyone has any ideas.

Devon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd take a look at this example I created. After you've created the LB, when creating each NIC make sure you add a backlink to the LB.

```
  load_balancer_backend_address_pool_ids = ["${azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.webservers_lb_backend.id}"]
```

[Terraform load balanced server](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/main/examples/traffic-manager/vm-scale-set/modules/region/3-vm-scale-set.tf)

Comment: This worked for me.. I had to change it to `load_balancer_backend_address_pools_ids` .. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "backend_pool" {
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  loadbalancer_id     = "${azurerm_lb.lb.id}"
  name                = "BackendPool1"
}

resource "azurerm_lb_nat_rule" "tcp" {
  resource_group_name            = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  loadbalancer_id                = "${azurerm_lb.lb.id}"
  name                           = "RDP-VM-${count.index}"
  protocol                       = "tcp"
  frontend_port                  = "5000${count.index + 1}"
  backend_port                   = 3389
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = "LoadBalancerFrontEnd"
  count                          = 2
}
```

You can get the whole file at this [link](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/master/examples/2-vms-loadbalancer-lbrules/variables.tf). I think the code above is the most import thing. For more details about Load Balancer NAT rule, see [azurerm_lb_nat_rule](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/loadbalancer_nat_rule.html).

Comment: This helps!! If I have a VM already built, how can I add the existing VM to the LB?

Comment: not sure that's possible as the VM and NIC are associated when the VM is created. You can import the VM as Data into terraform but not sure if it can then be modified. I'd do a destroy and then re-apply.

Answer (score 2):

Might be late to answer this, but here goes. Once you have created LB and VM, you can use this snippet to associate NIC and LB backend pool:

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "vault" {
  network_interface_id    = "${azurerm_network_interface.nic.id}"
  ip_configuration_name   = "nic_ip_config"
  backend_address_pool_id = "${azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.nic.id}"
}
```

Ensure that the VMs sit across availability set. Else you won't be able to register the VMs into the LB.

Answer (score 1):

All of the answers here appear to be outdated. [azurerm_network_interface_nat_rule_association](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/network_interface_nat_rule_association) should be used as of 2021-08-22:

```
resource "azurerm_lb_nat_rule" "example" {
  resource_group_name            = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  loadbalancer_id                = azurerm_lb.example.id
  name                           = "RDPAccess"
  protocol                       = "Tcp"
  frontend_port                  = 3389
  backend_port                   = 3389
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = "primary"
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "example" {
  name                = "example-nic"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "testconfiguration1"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.example.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface_nat_rule_association" "example" {
  network_interface_id  = azurerm_network_interface.example.id
  ip_configuration_name = "testconfiguration1"
  nat_rule_id           = azurerm_lb_nat_rule.example.id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/network_interface_backend_address_pool_association) is what you need. You then need to create the association between the network interface and the virtual machine thru the subnet.